# Spring Thymeleaf returns same body for two different requests

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have 2 users with 2 requests which have the same template for the response, but which have different data.

If I try to process both requests at the same time, it returns the same data for both requests. I have disabled all caches and used a debug header. The headers are different but the bodies are the same. All the logs show that 2 requests are processed successfully, with the right content selected.

But it still displays identical data in the browser.

The Thymeleaf configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfiguration{
    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setOrder(1);
        templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);

        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        templateEngine.addDialect(new Java8TimeDialect());
        templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
        return templateEngine;
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
    @GetMapping
    public String index(
            HttpServletRequest request, Model model,
            @RequestParam(name = "page", defaultValue = "0") int page,
            @RequestParam(name = "size", defaultValue = "20") int size,
            @RequestParam(name = "status", required = false) Integer status,
            @RequestParam(name = "fileName", required = false) String fileName
    ) {
        try {
            loadUser(request);
            Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size,
                    Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "updatedAt"));
            RequestFile.Status rStatus = RequestFile.Status.ofValue(status);
            Page<RequestFile> requestFiles = requestFileService.findAll(fileName, 
                rStatus, null, null, currentUser.getBranch(), null, pageable);
            model.addAttribute("requestFiles", requestFiles);
            model.addAttribute("currentUser", currentUser);
            model.addAttribute("status", status);
            model.addAttribute("fileName", fileName);
            model.addAttribute("curr", page);
            return "index";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove the template engine, spring boot configures that for you. You are storing the current user in some shared variable don't do that.

Comment: Yep... this line: `loadUser(request);` looks like it has side effects for sure. You *really* shouldn't define member variables (like `currentUser`) on your controller.